# What kind of relationship should be used for tables Transaction and User - Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, database-migration

I am new learner. I just started learning more about Backend with Ruby on Rails.
I have the following tables - User and User_Transaction.

So basically I want to have a transaction which holds information about the sender and the receiver. This personally sounds to me more like a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. However, I am really confused in how to approach this and how should I include the 2 foreign keys.
I am curious to learn more about this and I will be really happy if someone helps me :).

**Migrations**
User

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :username
      t.integer :password
      

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Transaction

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.string :sender
      t.string:receiver
      t.decimal :amount
      

      t.timestamps
    end

  end
end
```

**Models**

Transaction

```
class ::Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  #We have two users per transaction 'Sender' and 'Receiver'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    # belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
    # belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # has_many :accounts
  # has_many :transactions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :transactions

end
```

Comment: Applying the proposed solution from below - Haven't found a solution yet. I am wondering if more cols should be introduced ? Since I get `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#14620) expected, got 1 which is an instance of Integer(#4340))` when I try to create a transaction record the following way  `Transaction.create(:sender => "ff",:receiver => "ss", :amount =
> 100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this:

**migrations**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.references :sender, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
      t.references :receiver, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
      t.decimal :amount
      
      t.timestamps
    end

  end
end
```

**models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :send_transactions, class_name: "Transaction", foreign_key: :sender, inverse_of: :sender
  has_many :receive_transactions, class_name: "Transaction", foreign_key: :receiver, inverse_of: :receiver
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :send_transactions
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :receive_transactions
end
```

Comment: I inserted 2 users and when I tried user = User.find(2) I got the following , same for the first one - username: 0 why Is that ? ```
=> #<User id: 2, username: 0, password: [FILTERED], details: nil, created_at: "2020-11-27 12:08:09", updated_at: "2020-11-27 12:08:09">```

Comment: lol! i copied and pasted your code, and you have the "username" as an "integer" ... you'll want it to be a "string" instead and then it'll probably work fine, I'll edit my answer!

Comment: I still get a weird error - ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#14540) expected, got "filip" which is an instance of String(#4280))  after doing the following t = Transaction.create(:sender => "filip",:receiver => "George"
, :amount => 100)

Comment: isn't it a case where the foreign keys should be kept int and another col name as string to be added ?  I got really confused at this point I am really sorry ...

Comment: you need to create the user objects, then use those objects in the new create: `User.create(username: "filip", password: "abcd"); User.create(username: "George", password: "efgh"); Transaction.create(sender: User.first, receiver: User.last, amount: 100);`

Comment: Yes, It works ! Thank you very much ! May I ask one more question apart from that I am marking your answer as correct.  I get the same issue when I try to use those values in the following code `params.require(:transaction).permit(:sender, :receiver, :amount, :reference) ` and then passing it to  `Transaction.new(transaction_params)` just to note transaction_params is a separate function containing the above line of code

Comment: you might want to permit the sender_id and receiver_id, rather than the sender and receiver, but they;ll need to be the "id"s of the User object in both cases

Comment: But in the case where those values are given as input in a form for example how should be done ?

Comment: get the form to return the "id"s of the users, rather than the user object (pretty much the default in HTML, if you're using selects). `collection_select(:transaction, :receiver_id, User.all, :id, :username, prompt: true)` or something similar